# Hibernate c3p0 configuration has no affect

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I'm trying to add c3p0 connection pool to our existing hibernate configuration. 
But it has no affect and hibernate still uses default pool. 
Hibernate Configuration alone is working fine so i am absolutely sure no problem with it.

Wondering if someone here can point my mistake Or suggest how i can debug the problem ?

I do not use Spring framework.

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>

<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">passwd</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:db2://server:port/database</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">username</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">DB Schema</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DB2Dialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">4</property>
    <property name="hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation">1</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">3000</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">900</property>

<mapping resource="table.hbm.xml" />

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Here are the jars i have:

```
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-c3p0-3.5.0-Final.jar
```

Statements from the logs:

```
hibernate.cfg.Environment - Hibernate 3.5.0-Final
INFO  ManagerConnectionProvider - Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
INFO  ManagerConnectionProvider - Hibernate connection pool size: 20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try configuring a connection provider class from `c3p0`.

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

Also, it's better to add the hibernate configuration doctype, which will help in finding any typos.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

**UPDATE**
You need to include the mchange library in your classpath. This [link](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-errorinitial-sessionfactory-creation-failed-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-commchangev2c3p0datasources/) might helpful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have tried adding your suggestion with provider class and it resulted in the below mentioned error.

I'm checking more on the error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mchange/v2/c3p0/DataSources
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DataSources

And i do have doctype just that i did not provide in my query here, thought it is default expected. My apologies.

Comment: Thanks a ton it worked.

But i have to use c3p0-0.9.1.jar instead of the jar mentioned in my question.